# How to better display elements inside card?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, html-table, grid

i have a task where i should have information inside "card", it should be displayed like on my example(picture) [image]

so here is my html

```
<div id="app">
        <el-card shadow="always">
            Dashboard
        </el-card>

    <el-card class="box-card">
        <div slot="header">
            <h2>Card name</h2>
            <p>Challenge</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text item">

        </div>
    </el-card>
</div>
```

can you help me to place those "approved posts", "influences", "likes", "comments" like on picture?
let's say i don't have such big experience bud i think that i should use grid or table display...
can you show me some example or to show how could it be in my example?
Thank you!
i am using Vue.js and Element UI libruary

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicaly you need to follow col's, if you're familiar with bootstrap. so 2 equal col does the job

ex:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Posts</label>
            <label>545454</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Influencer</label>
            <label>56656</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Likes</label>
            label>545454</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label>Comments</label>
            <label>56656</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```